# RDP into a machine with out a user password

Tags: batch

The computers dont have passwords, even the admin account ass they are training units. But we cant RDP into them with out passwords.  I know the settings are at Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only, and  then disable.  But I need this in either powershell or preferably batch file. I have created single line batch files before but never this complex. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

## Manually:

```
1. Start > Run -> regedit

2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa

3. Now you want to edit  LimitBlankPasswordUse 
   0 = enable empty passwords on network
   1 = disable empty passwords on network
```

## By command:

```
 Reg.Exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" /v LimitBlankPasswordUse /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That didnt get me into the machines, either from dos prompt or from dos\powershell. I still get "user account restriction". What am I missing?